# How, Can I pass id from one to one activity

Tags: android, android-intent

In my adapter I have a code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("city_id", position);
 mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But, when in DetailActivity I use the code

```
city_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("city_id", 1);
```

city_id always = 1

I check the position in Log in Adapter and it not equally 1

Comment: Please add the relevant bits of the code which make your issue reproducible, considering what you said *here* is what you *observed for where the issue should be but isn't*, therefore we can't guess where your code goes wrong either.

Comment: One trivial explanation, which I doubt is your problem, is if `position` is not actually of type int. E.g. if `position` is a float then `getIntExtra()` would return the passed default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using city_id = (Integer)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("city_id") in DetailActivity. Hope this helps.